# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createNode' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler

Hi everyone need help to resolve ths problem.

[image]

i was tried to solve ths error

Comment: Please do not use screenshots hosted on 3rd party websites unless the screenshot contains critical visual information. Please instead simply copy and paste the error message you have received into your question. Also please list the steps you have tried to resolve this problem up till now.

Comment: My first guess is that you must properly install react-native-gesture-handler. Because it looks like that's the beginning of the error chain.